# How do I set a group of checkboxes using values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

So I have a group of checkboxes, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl1" name="cbl" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl2" name="cbl" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl3" name="cbl" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl4" name="cbl" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl5" name="cbl" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl6" name="cbl" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl7" name="cbl" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl8" name="cbl" value="8" />
```

Now I have an array of values:

```
var values = ["2", "4", "7", "8"];
```

Now how do I end up with my group of checkboxes to look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl1" name="cbl" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl2" name="cbl" value="2" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl3" name="cbl" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl4" name="cbl" value="4" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl5" name="cbl" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl6" name="cbl" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl7" name="cbl" value="7" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl8" name="cbl" value="8" checked="checked" />
```

Will I have to use two for-loops to do this? Is there a way in plain javascript or jquery that doesn't involve having to loop twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[API docs demo](http://api.jquery.com/val/#example-1-2)

```js
var values = ["2", "4", "7", "8"];

$('input[name="cbl"]').val(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl1" name="cbl" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl2" name="cbl" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl3" name="cbl" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl4" name="cbl" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl5" name="cbl" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl6" name="cbl" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl7" name="cbl" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbl8" name="cbl" value="8" />
```

Comment: Wow I actually didn't know this was possible. +1

Answer (score 2):

Create a selector from the array, and check them all

```
$( '#cbl' + values.join(', #cbl') ).prop('checked', true);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zahLcxco/)

This is using the ID's, as that's a better way to select the elements than the values, if you still want to use the values, you can use the same concept

```
$( '[value="' + values.join('"], [value="') + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zahLcxco/1/)

or you can filter

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(this.value, values) != -1;
}).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Look ma, no loops! :) +1

Comment: select by values, if values are what you have in your array